# Direct sum countably infinite

Tags: abstract-algebra, direct-sum, direct-product

Let $\{A_i:i\in N\}$ be a collection of nonempty sets. The direct sum of the collection is
$\bigoplus_{i\in N}A_i=\bigg\{(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots)\in\prod_{i\in N}A_i:a_i\neq0 \text{ for only finitely many }i\bigg\}.$

Let $\{A_i:i\in N\}$ be a collection of countably infinite sets. Show that $\bigoplus_{i\in N}A_i$ is countably infinite.

Attempt at solution: I realize that if the number of non-zero coordinates is finite, then one can order the coordinates in such a way that the natural numbers $N$ map onto the direct sum. I am new to the notation, though, and am having trouble constructing a formal proof. Would this involve some function from $N\times N\times N\times...$?

Comment: Just prove that the union of two countable sets is countable, then apply induction to prove the rest

Comment: That means if the Union of the first two sets is countable then consider the union to be a set on itself, take the Union of the third set and this new union set you created, and that is accountable because you just proved that the union of two countable sets is countable

Comment: Not relevant but note that the $A_i$ are probably not "sets" if you're taking their direct sum (and saying something about their elements equaling zero)...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: First show that for any $n \in N$, the subset $A^{(n)} = \{ (a_i) \in \bigoplus_{i \in N} A_i : a_k = 0 \text { for } k > n\}$ is countable, and then note that $\bigoplus_{i \in N} A_i$ is precisely the ascending countable union of countable sets $\bigcup_{n \in N} A^{(n)}$.